# Extracting Extended Entity Relationship Diagram from a Relational Database

Tags: sql-server, tools

I am researching how to extract an Extended Entity Relationship (EER) diagram from a Relational Database.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008.

I've found tools for Entity Relationship Diagrams (ER) on the Internet, however I haven't find any for EER.

Do you know where I might find anything on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

The only significant reference to the notation I've ever read is the Elmasri and Navathe textbook - EER gets taught in database papers from time to time, but I don't think it's widely used in practice..  I'm not aware of any data modelling tools with support for the notation.